# How to remove html tag from string but keep html entities intact

Tags: javascript, html, tags, entity, innerhtml

I would like to remove the HTML tags (element) from a string without touching the html entities such as &nbps; & é < etc..

For now I am using this :

```js
stringWithTag = "<i> I want to keep my ->&nbsp;<- element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i>";
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = stringWithTag;
    
    console.log("INPUT with html entity &nbsp;");
    console.log(stringWithTag);

    htmlNoTag = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
    console.log("\nOUTPUT that should still have entity &nbsp;, but not...");
    console.log(htmlNoTag);
```

cf jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/az4st8LL/

But I always miss the element entity (in that exemple &nbsp should still be visible but it is not the case).
I would like to avoid using a regex to remove all html tags if possible.

Does anyone has a solution to this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to avoid using regex, try

```
function stripTags(html) {
  var result = "";
  var add = true, c;
  for (var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
    c = html[i];
    if (c == '<') add = false;
    else if (c == '>') add = true;
    else if (add) result += c;
  }
  return result;
};
```

This will not work for
    `<i>I want to keep my ->&nbsp;<- element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i>` since you used `<` and `>` but will turn `<i> I want to keep my &nbsp; element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i>` into `I want to keep my &nbsp; element space, but remove the tags Please Help`

Comment: Thank you, you solutions works as you say. But in case of < or > in the code which is not part of the code, it will fail like you say. Do you have an alternate solution to avoid this ?

Comment: You can add a simple check to ignore a `>` if the code isn't currently walking through a tag, but the `<` is more difficult. On the other hand, shouldn't you use their html entities `&lt;` and `&gt;` for those anyway?

Comment: I am not the owner of the code I am parsing, therefore I can't tell how well structured is the HTML contained in my string. That's why I would like to take all possible cases in account.

Comment: You can parse ahead when you encounter a `<`, but it's going to get more and more complicated. Taking all possible cases into account is equivalent to writing a very error-tolerant parser. I'm sure there are libraries for this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a regex anyway (stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822464/1743938)):

```
string.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, '')
```

```js
stringWithTag = "<i> I want to keep my &nbsp; element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i>";

console.log(stringWithTag.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''));
```

I cheated a little bit by removing the "->" and "<-" from your string - since the regex matches everything between "<" and ">", those characters broke the demo.

Comment: Thank you, you solutions works as you say. But in case of < or > in the code which is not part of the code, it will fail like you say. Do you have an alternate solution to avoid this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex that searches for `tags` and reverse it. Then replace your string with this regex and `encodeURIComponent` values. Then you can `decodeURIComponent` when you need to use it.

```js
var stringWithTag = "<i> I want to keep my ->&nbsp;<- element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i><i> I want to keep my ->&nbsp;<- element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i><i> I want to keep my ->&nbsp;<- element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i><i> I want to keep my ->&nbsp;<- element space, but remove the tags <b>Please Help</b></i>";

var tags = stringWithTag.match(/(<[^>]>|<\/[^>]>)/g);
var startIndex = 0;
var str = "";

tags.reduce(function(p,c){
  var i = stringWithTag.indexOf(p, startIndex)+ p.length;
  var j = stringWithTag.indexOf(c, startIndex);
  str += p+ encodeURIComponent(stringWithTag.substring(i,j)) + c;
  startIndex = j;
  return c
})

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;

//console.log("INPUT with html entity &nbsp;");
//console.log(stringWithTag);

htmlNoTag = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
//console.log("\nOUTPUT that should still have entity &nbsp;, but not...");
console.log(decodeURIComponent(htmlNoTag));
```

#### Reference

- [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)
- [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thank you but your solution is only removing the first tag instead of all tags.